# Arduino Simulink missing .tlc file error

Tags: matlab, arduino, simulink

I am trying to run a simple simulink diagram on arduino using  what is provided in this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32374-matlab-support-for-arduino--aka-arduinoio-package-/content//simulink/arduinoCleanup.m).Unfortunately when i build the program i get this error:
"
The corresponding  'msfun_arduino_digitalwrite.tlc' file for the MATLAB S-function 'msfun_arduino_digitalwrite' in block 'untitled/Arduino Digital Write' must be located in the current working directory, the MATLAB S-function directory 'C:\Users\Mohamed Ali\Desktop\ArduinoIO\simulink', or the directory 'C:\Users\Mohamed Ali\Desktop\ArduinoIO\simulink\tlc_c'
"

I have been unsuccessfully looking   for the tlc file to place it.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Use http://uk.mathworks.com/hardware-support/arduino-simulink.html instead of the link you mentioned.

Comment: This library doesn t have encoder blocks neither interrupts.This is why i am working with the link i mentionned above.

Comment: The library you are using is out-of-date and unsupported, you should be using the one I mentioned instead. Additionally, it doesn't support code generation for running on the Arduino, it is only meant for running in Simulink. If you want to generate code, you need to use the official supported library.

Comment: OK, my mistake, the library you are using isn't out-of-date and unsupported (it was last updated in Sept 2014) but it is only for "communicating [from Simulink] with an Arduino board". You can't generate code from it and run it on the Arduino itself, like you are trying to do. To do that, you need to use the Arduino Support Package I mentioned.

Comment: Yeah i guess i got that.It is only used for communication which is not bad for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem. but after i used newer version of matlab and newer version of the support package i was able to generate automatically  all the files including tlc file.